# Should volatile be used when mapping GPU memory?

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu, volatile, vulkan

Both OpenGL and Vulkan allow to obtain a pointer to a part of GPUs memory by using `glMapBuffer` and `vkMapMemory` respectively. They both give a `void*` to the mapped memory. To interpret its contents as some data it has to be cast to an appropriate type. The simplest example could be to cast to a `float*` to interpret the memory as an array of floats or vectors or similar.

It seems that any kind of memory mapping [is undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340727/how-to-properly-access-mapped-memory-without-undefined-behavior-in-c) in C++, as it has no notion of memory mapping. However, this isn't really an issue because this topic is outside of the scope of the C++ Standard. However, there is still the question of `volatile`.

In the linked question the pointer is additionally marked as `volatile` because the contents of the memory it points at can be modified in a way that the compiler cannot anticipate during compilation. This seems reasonable though I rarely see people use `volatile` in this context (more broadly, this keyword seems to be barely used at all nowadays).

At the same time in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753903/memory-mapped-files-and-pointers-to-volatile-objects) the answer seems to be that using `volatile` is unnecessary. This is due to the fact that the memory they speak of is mapped using `mmap` and later given to `msync` which can be treated as modifying the memory, which is similar to explicitly flushing it in Vulkan or OpenGL. I'm afraid though that this doesn't apply to neither OpenGL nor Vulkan.

In case of the memory being mapped as not `GL_MAP_FLUSH_EXPLICIT_BIT` or it being `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT` than no flushing is needed at all and the memory contents update automagically. Even if the memory is flushed by hand by using `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` or `glFlushMappedBufferRange` neither of these functions actually takes the mapped pointer as a parameter, so the compiler couldn't possibly know that they modify the mapped memory's contents.

As such, **is it necessary to mark pointers to mapped GPU memory as `volatile`**? I know that technically this is all undefined behaviour, but I am asking what is required in practice on real hardware.

By the way, neither the [Vulkan Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2/pdf/vkspec.pdf) or the [OpenGL Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) mention the `volatile` qualifier at all.

EDIT: Would marking the memory as `volatile` incur a performance overhead?

Comment: don't worry about Undefined Behavior here because you are not talking about the abstract machine defined in the standard. You are talking about a specific implementation on a specific hardware and this implementation gives stronger guarantees than the standard does.

Comment: If the documentation tells you to mark it volatile, then do so. If it doesn't, then don't. Authors of this software know best how it works and how it interacts with hardware, so just listen to them. They provide this information in the types. Does `vkMapMemory` mention `volatile` *in the type*?

Comment: If the documentation doesn't say that `volatile` provides any guarantees, then it is literally completely useless to you. What you need is a guarantee of proper operation. If the platform doesn't give you one with `volatile`, then it's of no help at all. You are giving up compiler optimizations for nothing. If the compiler supports OpenGL and/or Vulkan, then it won't make optimizations that causes code that complies with those standards to do the wrong thing anyway. And if they're unsupported, you're in "gee, I hope it works" territory either way and should get out of that territory somehow.

Comment: If not addressed as `volatile` a clever (optimizing) compiler could decide that the region of memory being addressed could not (had not) been updated by the  program and remove all the reads of it.  Writes could also be optimized away if the compiler can prove program does not read the region of memory.

Comment: **For future readers**: using **non-temporal instructions** can make writing to persistent coherent video memory faster. Link: [Q on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37070/12501684).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, let's say that we have a compiler that is omniscient about everything that happens in your code. This means that the compiler can follow any pointer, even through the *runtime execution* of your code perfectly and correctly every time, no matter how you try to hide it. So even if you read a byte at one end of your program, the compiler will somehow remember the exact bytes you've read and anytime you try to read them again, it can choose to not execute that read and just give you the previous value, unless the compiler is aware of something that can change it.

But let's also say that our omniscient compiler is completely oblivious to everything that happens in OpenGL/Vulkan. To this compiler, the graphics API is a black box. Here, there be dragons.

So you get a pointer from the API, read from it, the GPU writes to it, and then you want to read that new data the GPU just wrote. Why would a compiler believe that the data behind that pointer has been altered; after all, the alterations came from outside of the system, from a source that the C++ standard does not recognize.

That's is what `volatile` is for, right?

Well, here's the thing. In both OpenGL and Vulkan, to ensure that you can actually read that data, you need to do something. Even if you map the memory coherently, you have to make an API call to ensure that the GPU process that wrote to the memory has actually executed. For Vulkan, you're waiting on a fence or an event. For OpenGL, you're waiting on a fence or executing a full finish.

Either way, before executing the read from the memory, the omniscient compiler encounters a function call into a black box which as established earlier the compiler knows *nothing* about. Since the mapped pointer itself came from the same black box, the compiler cannot *assume* that the black box doesn't have a pointer to that memory. So as far as the compiler is concerned, calling those functions *could have* written data to that memory.

And therefore, our omniscient-yet-oblivious compiler *cannot* optimize away such memory accesses. Once we get control back from those functions, the compiler *must* assume that any memory from any pointer reachable through that address could have been altered.

And if the compiler were able to peer into the graphics API itself, to read and understand what those functions are doing, then it would definitely see things that would tell it, "oh, I should not make assumptions about the state of memory retrieved through these pointers."

This is why you don't need `volatile`.

Also, note that the same applies to writing data. If you write to persistent, coherent mapped memory, you still have to perform some synchronization action with the graphics API so that your CPU writes so that the GPU isn't reading it. So that's where the compiler knows that it can no longer rely on its knowledge of previously written data.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Basically, calling any Vulkan function can potentially modify any memory as it is a black box. One thing bother me though: in the Standard they note that "volatile is a hint to the implementation to avoid aggressive optimization involving the object because the value of the object might be changed by means undetectable by an implementation". If this case is not "undetectable by an implementation" or at least unpredictable, then when at all would the use of `volatile` be needed?

Comment: @enthusiastic_3d_graphics_pr...: It would be needed by direct hardware management, where an address of memory is directly shared with some external device *without* any CPU intervention. Vulkan and OpenGL require some form of CPU intervention to make sure that the data exists.

Comment: Note that volatile is likely harmful as the compiler can't remove redundant read/writes to the memory buffer, between calls to the library.

Comment: @enthusiastic_3d_graphics_pr... The problem is, if `volatile` was necessary, you'd be totally screwed. You have no evidence that `volatile` is sufficient. You have provided a hint, but how do you know that hint is enough to disable the right optimizations? So if you have some other mechanism that is sufficient, you don't need `volatile` too. And if you don't have some other mechanism that is sufficient, you are just operating on hopes and wishes. You would only want `volatile` if you had something that specifically stated that it was sufficient with `volatile`.